# Binary Format of a Custom Attribute error adding microsoft.bcl.async

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf project, compiled as x86 code for framework 4.5, and as part of the migration process of some code to this project I have to add the **microsoft.bcl.async** package.
If I add this package and start compile I receive this error message **'Binary format of the specified custom attribute was invalid.'** and if I remove the package I can compile again.
Am I missing something?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: visual studio 2017 15.5.2

Comment: So why do you even need Microsoft.Bcl.Async then? This package enables Visual Studio 2012 projects to use the new 'async' and 'await' keywords. The latest compiler has this functionality built-in. If you are targeting .NET Framework 4.5 and use VS2017 you don't have no use for Microsoft.Bcl.Async.